# Mouse hover font size change on label

Tags: c#, winforms

Novice here, wanted to try to resize text in a label with a simple mouse over, but everything I seem to be trying isn't exactly working. Am I forgetting a property in the label? or is it the code?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.Name, 20, FontStyle.Regular);
    }

    private void OnMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.Name, 9, FontStyle.Regular);
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to attach your events didn't you:

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     label1.MouseEnter += OnMouseEnter;
     label1.MouseLeave += OnMouseLeave;
}
```

Or you can just do that through the designer.

Comment: Wow, thanks I apparently need to go to bed! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

when you change ui properties make sure to call Refresh() or Invalidate() method of that control

Comment: [Are you sure about that](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,2459)?

Comment: if altering properties linked with UI of that control like font or width, just a way for foerground thread to expliclilty handle new properties changes in queue to re render